# Using a method after casting in Java

Tags: java, casting, comparable, compareto

I have written the code:

```
public int compareTo(Object w) {
    //w = (Word)w

    if(this.count > (Word) w.getCount()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.count < (Word) w.getCount()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
}
```

I have written the class Word. It implements Comparable so I must use the Object parameter for the `compareTo()` method.

However, I need the object to use a method in the Word class. I get an error if I cast and was wondering if I am doing something wrong or if I need to try something else?

Word class:

```
package comp10152_lab3;

public class Word implements Comparable{
private int count;
private String word;

public Word(String word) {
    this.word = word;
    this.count = 1;
}


public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object w) {
  if(this.count > w.getCount()){
    return -1;
  }
  else if (this.count < w.getCount()) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
      return 0;
  }

}

public void countUp() {
    count++;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return word + "(" + count + ")";
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object w) {
    return w.equals(word);
}


}
```

The equals class is suppose to be that way, as per instruction.
The error I am getting is on the w.getCount() which is a "missing symbol" error.

Comment: What error are you getting when you cast?

Comment: you need to give more details about your problem. plz, post all the Word class code and error you are getting stuck.

Comment: Wrap the `(Word)w` in parentheses too: `((Word)w).getCount()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that you need:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
  Word w = (Word) o;
  if(this.count > w.getCount()){
    return -1;
  }
  else if (this.count < w.getCount()) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

The problem that you were having was due to the fact that `w` was of the type `Object`, the statement `w = (Word) w` would not do what you wanted. The second part of the problem has to do with the precedence of the cast operator in Java. When you do `(Word)w.getCount()`, the `getCount()` part gets evaluated first, meaning that you were effectively doing `(Word) <some int>`. What you could have done was wrap it in parentheses like `((Word) w).getCount()` to solve that problem.

Comment: Oh good Lord, I cannot believe I forgot about that. Thank you very kindly!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `Comparable<Word>` so that the compareTo method is `public int compareTo(Word w)`. Also you can simplify your compareTo code:

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

  private int count;

  public int compareTo(Word w) {
    return w.count - this.count;
  }
}
```

If you can't use java generics then you can still do your compareTo in one line:

```
public int compareTo(Object w) {
  return ((Word) w).count - this.count;
}
```